# sequelize updateAttributes fails if id has custom getter. How to make it ignore prefix attached by a getter

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a Sequelize model like the following:

```
 var BinaryParam = sequelize.define('BinaryParam', {
id: {
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  autoIncrement: true,
  primaryKey: true,
  get: function() {
    return "b"+this.getDataValue('id').toString();
  }
},
name: DataTypes.STRING,
description: DataTypes.TEXT,
nominal_value: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
in_use: {
  type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
  defaultValue: true
}
```

Please note that I have a custom getter on the id field, that prefixes the id with a 'b'.

I need to update an attribute on an instance of this model and am doing a find on the id (without the 'b' prefix on it) and if found, am trying to do an update on it:

```
models.BinaryParam.find({
            where: {
                id: id
            }
        }).then(function (param) {
            console.log('we found a param:', param);
            if (param) {
                    param.updateAttributes({
                    in_use: in_use
                }).then(function (param) {
                    callback(param);
                }).catch(function (error) {
                   console.log("Problem updating attribute:", error)
                });
            }
        });
```

What is happening is that the update query is trying to do an update with the b prefix on it and is not affecting the row in mysql at all.

The query that sequelize tries to run is:

```
Executing (default): UPDATE `BinaryParams` SET `in_use`=false,`updatedAt`='2016-08-21 14:20:34' WHERE `id` = 'b1'
```

Note that it is trying to use 'b1' in the WHERE when trying to update. This fails, because in the mysql table, the id field is an autoincrementing integer - i.e. in this case, it only has a 1, and it does not have the 'b' prefixed to it.

How can we ask updateAttributes to ignore the prefix that the getter applies?

What are my options for solving this problem.